# Can we say," The set of all compact metric spaces"?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, set-theory

1. Fix a compact topological space $X$. Whether $\{(Y,\phi): Y \text{ is a compact metric space and }\phi:X\to Y \text{ is surjective continuous map}\}$ is a set?
2. If $I$ is a set and for each $\alpha\in I$, $A_\alpha$ is a set. Is the collection $\{A_\alpha:\alpha\in I\}$ a set?

I am reading a proof of RRT for positive linear functionals articulated by V.S.Sunder and there the first  collection was assumed as a set. I couldn't able to prove it. Nonetheless, I have modified  the required set as  $\mathcal{B}:=\{E\subset X: \exists \text{ cpt m.s. }Y, ~\pi:X\to Y \text{ is surjective, and }E=\pi^{-1}(A),~A\in\mathcal{B}_\pi\}$ and enjoyed the nice proof! of prof.V.S.Sunder.

Ref: V.S. Sunder,   The Riesz representation theorem, Indian J. of Pure and Appl.
Math., 39(6), December 2008, 467-481.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/327533/156252

Comment: 2. Yes, this is the replacement axiom of ZF. For 1., literally *no*, though if homeomorphic spaces are regarded equal, then yes.

Comment: @Berci, Thank you...

Comment: The Hilbert Cube is $H=[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ with the usual topology on $[0,1$] and the Tychonoff product on $ H$..... $H$ is compact & metrizable. Any 2nd-countable $T_{3\frac {1}{2}}$ space is homeomorphic to a subspace of $H$. In particular a space is compact & metrizable iff it is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $H.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Thank you...

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3470502/classifying-whether-a-collection-of-objects-is-a-set/3471215#3471215.

Answer (score 3):

Your question reaches down to the foundation of set theory. A common approach is [Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) **ZF**. It does not define a *set* as a "collection of objects" or something like that (although that is a nice *intuitive understanding*), but gives a list of axioms which have to be satisfied by things called *sets*.

However, it turns out that some "collections" of objects which one can easily name, for example

- the collection of all sets,
- the collection of all compact metric spaces,

cannot be sets (if they were sets, we would get contradictions as Russell's paradox). Such collections are called *proper classes*, and in a sense they are too big to satisfy all axioms of **ZF**. For example, there is no set containing as elements *all* sets and no set of *all* compact metric spaces.

Concerning your questions:

1. The compact metric spaces do not form a set. This is not a drama, because it is possible to find a *set of representatives*. If you are satisfied with compact *metrizable* toplogical spaces (i.e. if you are not interested in specific metrics because all metrics generating the same compact topology on a given set are uniformly equivalent), then Daniel Wainfleet's comment shows what to do: The closed subspaces of the Hilbert cube $Q$ form a set $\mathfrak C$. All $X \in  \mathfrak C$ are compact metrizable and each compact metrizable space is homeomorphic to some member of $\mathfrak C$. If you want to consider compact *metric* spaces, then it is just a little more complicated. The previous argument shows that each compact metric space $(X,d)$ admits a *bijection* $\phi : X \to X'$ to a subset $X'$ of $Q$. This $\phi$ induces a metric $d_\phi$ on $X'$ making $(X,d)$ and $(X',d_\phi)$ isometrically isomorphic. The metrics on a given set $X'$ form a set, thus 2. shows that all pairs $(X',d')$ where $X'$ is a subset of the Hilbert cube (i.e. a member of the power set of $Q$) and $d'$ is a metric on $X'$ also form a set $\mathfrak M$. Not all such $(X',d')$ are compact, but the subset $\mathfrak M_c$ of compact $(X',d') \in \mathfrak M$ gives you the desired set of representatives for the class of compact metric spaces.
2. Yes. As Berci comments, this is the replacement axiom of **ZF**.

Comment: Thank you very much