# Why define simplicial chain groups as functions rather than free Abelian groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I am trying to understand why the usual definition of chain groups goes

1. Define $n$-chains as maps from $n$-simplices to $\mathbb{Z}$ that vanish cofinitely
2. Prove $C_n$ is free Abelian

Why not start with definition of $C_n$ as free Abelian? I saw this in a bunch of different lecture notes on the internet, but textbooks seem to prefer the definition in terms of maps. I would appreciate if someone could point me to where this simplification fails or what is the "profit" gained in intuition or otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a free abelian group? By universal property or some construction?

Comment: Maybe the authors of textbooks don't want to presuppose that the readers know about free abelian groups.   So they begin with a construction of these groups rather than the universal property.

Comment: A lot of authors *do* define $C_n$ as the free abelian group on the simplices, e.g. Hatcher or tom Dieck. I don't think there really is any benefit to the definition in terms of maps and since these definitions are rather immediately seen to be equivalent, there isn't any substantial difference either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do so.

An Abelian group $F$ is called free if it has a *basis*. This is a subset $B \subset F$ such that each $x \in F$ has a unique representation as finite sum $x = \sum_{i=1}^n n_i b_i$ with $n_i \in \mathbb Z$ and $b_i \in B$. Frequently one wants to start with a set $X$ and find a free Abelian group $F$ having $X$ as a basis. This leads to the following definition:

Given a set $X$, an Abelian group $F(X)$ together with a function $\iota : X \to F(X)$ is called *freely generated by $X$* if for every Abelian group $G$ and every function  $f : X \to G$ there exists a unique group homomorphism $\bar f :  F(X)\to G$ such that $f = \bar f \circ \iota$.

This definition via a *universal property* determines the pair $(F(X),\iota)$ uniquely up to canonical isomorphism. In fact, if $\iota' : X \to F'(X)$ has the same property, then we get unique group homomorphims $\bar \iota' : F(X) \to F'(X)$ such that $\iota' = \bar \iota' \circ \iota$ and  $\bar \iota' : F(X) \to F'(X)$ such that $\iota = \bar \iota \circ \iota'$. Hence $\bar \iota \circ \bar \iota' \circ \iota = \bar \iota \circ \iota' = \iota =  id_{F(X)} \circ \iota$ which implies $\bar \iota \circ \bar \iota' = id_{F(X)}$ via uniqueness. Similarly $\bar \iota' \circ \bar \iota = id_{F'(X)}$.

It remains to prove the *existence* of such a pair $(F(X),\iota)$. The standard construction is $F(X) = \{ \phi : X \to \mathbb Z \mid \phi(x) \ne 0 \text{ only for finitely many } x \in X \}$ and $\iota(x')(x) = 1$ for $x' = x$, $\iota(x')(x) = 0$ for $x' \ne x$. We do not go into details here, you can consult a textbook. Note that this $F(X)$ is easily seen to be a free Abelian group with basis $\iota(X)$ which justifies the notation *freely generated by $X$*.

Now let us come to your question. Defining $C_n$ as **the** free Abelian group generated by the $n$-simplices is not really precise because there are many models for such an object. For example, if you have only one $0$-simplex, you could simply take $C_0 = \mathbb Z$. But you want to obtain a *functor* $C_n$ and therefore it is not expedient to say "pick **any** free Abelian group generated by the $n$-simplices" - doing so would involve a variant of the axiom of choice for proper classes. Concerning *classes* have a look at [Can we say," The set of all compact metric spaces"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3923253)

This problem can easily be avoided by taking a *concrete construction* of free Abelian groups, for example that as *maps* as above. We do not need any choice here.

Comment: Thank you, this points me in a very clear direction! I'm not sure though I understand the argument: we get that every free(ly generated) Abelian is unique up to isomorphism, so why can't we talk about **the** free Abelian group generated by $n$-simplices? Is canonical isomorphism something else, or by models you mean something that excludes up-to-isomorphism from satisfactory constructions? I apologize, my algebra background is limited.

Comment: @locally_convex The point is this: For each set $X$ there exists a free Abelian group $F(X)$ generated by $X$ and it is unique *up to isomorphism* - but it is not unique. Indeed, there are many pairs $(F(X), \iota)$ having the universal property in my answer. If we call any such pair a *model* of a free Abelian group generated by $X$, this means that are many different models. Yes, these are "essentially the same object", i.e. agree up to isomorphism, but they are not identical.  To get a *functor* from sets to free Abelian gropus we must assign to each $X$ a *single model*

Comment: of a free Abelian group generated by $X$. A good approach is to specify a standard construction producing a free Abelian group $F(X)$ generated by $X$, for example the "map-construction" in my answer, and define this specific $F(X)$ to be **the** free Abelian group generated by $X$. If you are not willing to do so, you get a problem. You could say "Let us pick **any model** of a free Abelian group generated by $X$". But this "picking approach" would involve a *choice* for each $X$. And here you go down to the foundation of set theory (see my above link).

Comment: You can make a choice for finitely many sets $X$ or, if you use the axiom of choice, for any *set* of sets $X$. But it is not possible for *all* sets $X$ - these form a proper class.